# Why does my vim colorscheme stay after I close vim?

Tags: linux, bash, vim, terminal

I recently used vundle to install the solarized theme for vim on my Arch Linux machine. Whenever I open vim, the theme is applied, but it stays applied to my terminal window after I close it. I can get rid of the colorscheme with some commands, like `ls`, but not others, like `clear`. Anyone know why this is happening? How do I fix it?

*[image: When vim is open]

[image: After closing and typing ls]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems vim doesn't send the correct reset sequences when you quit. `ls` colors parts of its output, so it resets to default when it's finished.

You can reset the terminal by sending the proper escape sequence - `printf '\e[0m'` is probably the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks. I put that after a VimLeave statement and it worked. It told me it wasn't a valid editor command when I opened vim, though. Do you know where that command should be? Right now there's a "VimLeave printf '\e[0m'" line at the bottom of my .vimrc

Comment: Try `au VimLeave printf....` instead of `VimLeave printf...`

Comment: When I add that I have the same problem I did initially; it doesn't clear the colorscheme.

Comment: After adding an asterisk after VimLeave on that last line, it worked. The sourceforge vim documentation is down, so I don't know exactly what's happening here. If you do and could explain that to me as well, I'd appreciate it. Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: The most common reason Vim doesn't handle the terminal properly (as in this case) is that the TERM environmental variable is not being properly set.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Guntram's answer, `set t_te="^[[H^[[2J,"` in your .vimrc should insure it happens when you exit and might inadvertently be the issue. It's often set to blank because the default also repaints the screen and many people don't like that. This isn't an issue if not using color, but obviously is if you do.